# How can I generate random observations from a concrete copula?

Tags: correlation, random-generation, copula, multivariate-distribution

Let us assume that we have two continuous random variables $X$, $Y$, with known distributions (not necessarily normal), connected/related via a concrete copula.

What is a procedure to generate random values from this pair $(X,Y)$?

For a single random variable $X$, I usually generate (pseudo)random values within $[0,1]$ and then transform them into observations of $X$ using its inverse-[CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function). Can I do the same when I have copulas?

I am asking for a generic procedure/recipe.

Answer (score 8):

Copulas are [usually defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)#Mathematical_definition) via the joint cdf of the Uniform components,
$$ C(u_1,u_2,\dots,u_d)=\mathbb P[U_1\leq u_1,U_2\leq u_2,\dots,U_d\leq u_d]$$
Unfortunately, a value $C(u_1,u_2,\dots,u_d)$ computed from a random realisation from $C$ is *not* a Uniform variate as in the univariate case.

In the bivariate case, simulation of $(U_1,U_2)$ could proceed by the *conditional method:*

1. generating $U_1\sim\mathcal U(0,1)$ [since the marginal is Uniform]
2. generating $U_2$ conditional on $U_1$

The second step will depend on the format of $C(u_1,u_2)$:

1. The conditional cdf of $U_2$ is given by$$F(u_2|u_1)=\frac{\partial C}{\partial u_1}(u_1,u_2)\Big/\frac{\partial C}{\partial u_1}(u_1,\infty)$$and the inverse cdf method can be used if inverting the above $F$ in $u_2$ is easily done
2. The conditional pdf of $U_2$ is given by$$f(u_2|u_1)\propto\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial u_1\partial u_2}(u_1,u_2)$$and standard simulation techniques apply when this function is available.

Historically, Devroye (1986, [Chapter XI](http://www.eirene.de/Devroye.pdf)) has two entire sections XI.3.2. and XI.3.3 on the topic (even though he does not use the term *copula* despite them being [introduced in 1959](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-011-3466-8_2) by A, Sklar, in response to a query of M. Fréchet). These sections contain many examples (as for instance the Table on page 585) but no generic simulation method.

Answer (score 7):

A recipe for how to generate random observations depends on the level of detail. If you can generate from the copula, then you get points on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$. Then you transform the $X$ coordinate into $X$ and the $Y$ coordinate into $Y$ by using their respective inverse CDFs.

Comment: For instance, to simulate a Gaussian copula, generate$$\mathbf X\sim\mathcal N_p(0,\boldsymbol{\Sigma})$$and take$$\mathbf U=(\Phi(X_1),\ldots,\Phi(X_p))$$Then transform back with the chosen marginal inverse $F^{-1}$.