# Sampling from bivariate conditional distribution

Tags: distributions, sample, quantiles

I would like to sample from a bivariate conditional distribution $F(y_1, y_2 |X_1 = x_1, ..., X_p=x_p)$, where the distribution is determined non-parametrically. How can I sample from such a distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Once one observes the realisation
$$X_1 = x_1, ..., X_o=x_o$$
the values $x_1,\ldots,x_o$ are fixed and known. Hence the conditional cdf (I assume this is a cdf)
$$F(y_1, y_2 |X_1 = x_1, ..., X_o=x_o)$$
is a function of $(y_1,y_2)$ only and a regular cdf, for which [standard simulation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/579101/7224) techniques apply.

Comment: Thank you! But if the cdf $F$ is an empirical distribution (non-differentiable), this standard simulation technique does not work in my opinion. That's what I am struggeling with.

Comment: @anjo1659: The question does not mention anything like this so you should rephrase it to reflect on your actual difficulties and repost it as another question.